# Scrape website with php curl which has GET only and no Form Data

Tags: php, web-scraping, php-curl

I've been trying to web scrape https://www.biathlonworld.com/athletes/search/familyname/0/givenname/0/gender/w/yearbirth/0/country/0/page/0/count/20/ with cURL GET but I end up just with the basic links, not athletes there. I would like to list the athletes, 20 at a time, and then update the page number to get the next 20.

In the XHR, I see

**Request Method: GET

Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin

X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff

X-Frame-Options: deny

X-Powered-By: ASP.NET**

I get this response with POST *The page you are looking for cannot be displayed because an invalid method (HTTP verb) is being used*

Any idea how to solve this to get the athletes as you do in a normal browser with that link?

```
$ch = curl_init('https://www.biathlonworld.com/athletes/search/familyname/0/givenname/0/gender/w/yearbirth/0/country/0/page/0/count/20/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; pl; rv:1.9.2.3) Gecko/20100401 Firefox/3.6.3");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'familyname=0&givenname=0&gender=w&yearbirth=0&country=0&page=0');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['x-requested-with: XMLHttpRequest']);
```

Comment: If you open the developers console and load the page ( as linked to ) you should see loads of XHR requests, one of which appears to return that data about athletes etc. As cURL does not work with javascript you either need to use a headless browser ( such as `casper` ) or target that same particular endpoint to process the json data

Comment: The url to curl for seems to be https://www.biathlonworld.com/api/v1/sportdata/athletes/search/0/0/w/0/0/0/20/ where you may receive the raw json

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius, do you have any example (code) for that?

Comment: @steven, that works, how did you find that url?

Comment: @nib if you load their site and open your dev-tools in chrome, take a look at the network tab and you can see that the api is loaded via xhr request.

Comment: ah, it was there all the time @steven